In a writing test, if the question uses British terms, but I tend to follow American style guides, should I use the American terms instead?
In a writing test where I need to report data given in a table, if the question uses British terms, but I tend to follow American style guides, should I use the equivalent American terms instead?
For example, if the question mentions underground railway systems, can I switch to "subway systems" or should I just report data using the given term?

In a test, you should follow the rules of the test. If you are unsure about them or they are unclear, you should ask the person or institution conducting the test.
Generally, a style guide prescibes no specific language or variety of a language. You can follow an American style guide and write in Spanish. What variety of English you should use is determined by your audience.
In a test, where you usually have an audience of one person, and that person might not be a native speaker of the (variety of the) language spoken in the place where the test takes place, you should inquire with them.
If there is no rule, and your corrector expresses no preference, write in whichever variety of English you prefer.

Edit after your comment
The official website for the IELTS states:

There is no preference when it comes to IELTS. Using British or American English won’t make any difference to your score. However, even though you do not need to be 100% consistent when writing, it is good practice to try and be as consistent as you can in using either British or American English spelling.


I guess I should have been more specific. It's the IELTS test, which means that I can't ask anybody about it because I don't know the examiners, and the test doesn't specify such a rule. That's why I'm asking for the most common way a native speaker would write it to be on the safe side.

@user63970 I have updated my answer.

Thanks a lot, Ben! It seems that I had missed this part of the guidelines.
